# Refresh a Combobox in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, camera

I have a function that detects camera ports in 3D slicer, however it seems to only run once. When I unplug/plug in a camera, the number of ports should update in a combobox (designed in Qt), but nothing changes.

The function I'm using detects when the camera port is clicked:

```
void qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget::onCameraPortClicked(){
  Q_D(qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget);

  // Clear current entries
  d->CameraPortComboBox->clear();

  int n = 0;

  // Loop over camera ports until last one is found. Add all available ports to combo box and exit.
  while(1){ 
    cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture(n);


    if(!cap.isOpened()){ 
      return;
    }
    QString portNum = QString::fromStdString(std::to_string(n++));
    d->CameraPortComboBox->addItem(portNum);
    qSlicerCoreApplication::processEvents();
  }
}
```

The setup function runs last and assigns the GUI to the actual function.

```
connect( d->CameraPortComboBox,   SIGNAL(clicked()),  this, SLOT(onCameraPortClicked()));
```

I need it to refresh and try to detect the cameras every time the combobox is clicked on, but because of the interface setup I am not sure if it is possible. I don't think constantly refreshing the program is a good option, so I'm out of ideas. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yikes. You can write "QString portNum = QString::number(n++);" without the std::string intermediary, fwiw.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but are you sure there isn't some way this would be possible?

Comment: I think that refreshing the combo every time it is clicked is OK, but you'd need to do the detection in a separate thread, and then update the combo once the detection has finished. Please, for your own good, consider `processEvents` calls to be bugs. They almost always are bugs when used by beginners. Heck, I have a 60k line heavily interactive code base without a single `processEvents` and `waitFor...` calls, and with the only `exec` calls being for the main event loop and `QDrag` where it's unfortunately necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the camera list in another thread:

```
void qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget::onCameraPortClicked() {
  QtConcurrent::run([this]{
    QStringList cameras;
    for (int i = 0; true; ++i) {
      auto cap = cv::VideoCapture(i);
      if (! cap.isOpened()) break;
      cameras << QString::number(i);
    }
    // This is a queued, thread-safe call. It will execute in the
    // GUI thread.
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "onCameraList", 
                              Q_ARG(QStringList, cameras));
  });
}

// another slot
void qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget::onCameraList(const QStringList & cameras) {
  Q_D(qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget);
  d->CameraPortComboBox->clear();
  for (auto portNum : cameras)
    d->CameraPortComboBox->addItem(portNum);
}
```

Also note that a combo box doesn't have a `clicked()` signal. You need to install an event filter on the combo box to get access to the events you're interested in. Perhaps you could use the `Enter` event instead, too:

```
class EventSignaller : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
      emit entered(qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj));
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
      emit clicked(qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj));
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
  }
public:
  EventSignaller(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
  Q_SIGNAL void entered(QWidget*);
  Q_SIGNAL void clicked(QWidget*);
  void track(QWidget * widget) {
    widget->removeEventFilter(this); // ensure we're unique
    widget->installEventFilter(this);
  }
};

qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget::qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget() : ... {
  auto signaller = new EventSignaller(this);
  connect(signaller, SIGNAL(entered(QWidget*)), // or SIGNAL(clicked(QWidget*))
                     SLOT(updateCameraPorts()));
  ...
}

void qSlicerTrackingModuleWidget::updateCameraPorts() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I like this implementation and was unaware that Qt provided simplistic threading for things like this (I suppose it should have been obvious for a UI library :p ), but I don't think this will resolve the issue of the signal not being triggered in the first place. My code as it stands updates the list correctly so long as it is called, but the call isn't occurring. Does your code address this and I'm just missing it? Just for clarity, it's not a button I'm connecting to but a combobox

Comment: @GenevieveCcio It's up to you what criteria do you want to trigger on. Remember that a combo box doesn't have a "clicked" signal. You might want to trigger a re-scan when the mouse enters the box. There's no signal for it, but you can filter the `Enter` even on the combo box to detect this - without need for subclassing the control.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'll test it out in a bit and get back to you.